# No muestra estilos css y bootstrap proyecto CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

estoy elaborando un proyecto en codeigniter, al momento de probarlo no me muestra los estilos y manda los siguientes errores:

jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function @http://localhost/superlogin/assets/js/custom.js:6:26

Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/superlogin/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js
Source Map URL: popper.min.js.map

Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/superlogin/assets/css/style.css
Source Map URL: style.css.map

Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/superlogin/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map

Para mandar a traer los codigos los tengo de la siguiente manera:

assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

">

De favor alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema.

Comment: Juan Daniel , revisa tus versiones de Jquery / Pooper, y Bootstrap, yo tuve que estar descargando en varias ocasiones las librerías para que me funcionara correctamente, déjame ver si puedo colocar una imagen del directorio que tengo de todas las librerías que coloque en mi proyecto actual y como te digo el orden de css, js si afecta en la funcionalidad cuando los cargas, checa eso creo que por ahí va el asunto, deja tratar de checar que versiones de cada librería descargue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira esta es la cabecera del datatables.js  lo descargue del sitio: 
https://datatables.net/download/

Solo que ya no recuerdo si descargue la version "nativa" o la que hace referencia bootstrap 4, ya que en alguna parte lei que si ya tienes bootstrap no requieres descargar esa versión.

```
  /*
 * This combined file was created by the DataTables downloader builder:
 *   https://datatables.net/download
 *
 * To rebuild or modify this file with the latest versions of the included
 * software please visit:
 *   https://datatables.net/download/#dt/jq-3.3.1/pdfmake-0.1.36/dt-1.10.20/af-2.3.4/b-1.6.1/b-colvis-1.6.1/b-flash-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/cr-1.5.2/fc-3.3.0/fh-3.1.6/kt-2.5.1/r-2.2.3/rg-1.1.1/rr-1.2.6/sc-2.0.1/sl-1.3.1
 *
 * Included libraries:
 *   jQuery 3 3.3.1, pdfmake 0.1.36, DataTables 1.10.20, AutoFill 2.3.4, Buttons 1.6.1, Column visibility 1.6.1, Flash export 1.6.1, HTML5 export 1.6.1, Print view 1.6.1, ColReorder 1.5.2, FixedColumns 3.3.0, FixedHeader 3.1.6, KeyTable 2.5.1, Responsive 2.2.3, RowGroup 1.1.1, RowReorder 1.2.6, Scroller 2.0.1, Select 1.3.1
 */

/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1
 * https://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * https://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright JS Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2018-01-20T17:24Z
 */
```

Esta es mi versión del bootstrap que es la que me ha funcionado sin problemas con el datatable.

```
/*!
```

* Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

Esta es mi versión de Jquery

/*! jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2020-01-08
* http://jqueryui.com
* Includes: widget.js, position.js, data.js, disable-selection.js, focusable.js, form-reset-mixin.js, jquery-1-7.js, keycode.js, labels.js, scroll-parent.js, tabbable.js, unique-id.js, widgets/draggable.js, widgets/droppable.js, widgets/resizable.js, widgets/selectable.js, widgets/sortable.js, widgets/accordion.js, widgets/autocomplete.js, widgets/button.js, widgets/checkboxradio.js, widgets/controlgroup.js, widgets/datepicker.js, widgets/dialog.js, widgets/menu.js, widgets/mouse.js, widgets/progressbar.js, widgets/selectmenu.js, widgets/slider.js, widgets/spinner.js, widgets/tabs.js, widgets/tooltip.js, effect.js, effects/effect-blind.js, effects/effect-bounce.js, effects/effect-clip.js, effects/effect-drop.js, effects/effect-explode.js, effects/effect-fade.js, effects/effect-fold.js, effects/effect-highlight.js, effects/effect-puff.js, effects/effect-pulsate.js, effects/effect-scale.js, effects/effect-shake.js, effects/effect-size.js, effects/effect-slide.js, effects/effect-transfer.js
* Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors; Licensed MIT */

Espero que te sirva de algo estas referencias, es lo mas que puedo aportar, como ya te mencione tenia el mismo problema, tuve que estar revisando cada carga de los scripts de las librerías, quitar y poner css, js, etc etc, hasta que me dejo de enviar esos errores, cambiar una y otra vez las versiones hasta que ya me quedo trabajando sin problema.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

yo no uso CodeIgniter, en varias ocasiones se me ha presentado algunos problemas para poder ver los dataTables, son situaciones muy sencillas, cuando se me presento el problema similar al que mencionas: "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function " por lo general es un error "heredado" me ocurrio que tenia mal la cantidad de renglones declarados en el `<thead>` contra los que tenia declarados en el `<tbody>`, puede ser incluso un `<td></td> <th></th>` mal cerrado o que no tenga un valor que mostrar.

Asegurate de poner tus librerías requeridas para cada sección de código que requiere javascript , jquery etc.

La otra es que tus llamadas de las librerias de acuerdo a lo que indica no las encuentra, yo las tengo declaradas así, solo te pongo un ejemplo, pero te recuerdo no uso codeigniter.

Espero te sea de ayuda mi pequeña contribución

Saludos

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución considera revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Gracias bro, pues me sigue mostrando el mismo error y no me manda estilos

Comment: Amigo no he podido solucionarlo, me gustaria poder recibir mas asesoria de tu parte algun medio donde pueda contactarte de favor?

Comment: Buen día Juan Daniel, veo que ya le diste palomita a una de mis respuestas, pero no has comentado nada sobre si ya resolviste el detalle que tienes.  Deja seguir resolviendo unos problemas que tengo por aca, y en un par de horas reviso si ya comentaste algo. Saludos.